# Quick question about Qt with C++

Tags: c++, qt

I can't download the Qt IDE right now as it is about 1.5GBs, and my internet connection is limited to 60Kb/s with a download limit of 500MBs. So, excuse my curiosity as I won't be able to try Qt before quite some time.

The question is: If I want to use the DB, GUI, and Networking features of Qt, what is the typical size of a "hello world" program that includes libraries for these?

Also, should Qt be installed on a computer like .Net Framework for programs to run?

Again, excuse me as I can't try Qt right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "hello world" application using those modules on Windows would probably come in over 5 MB. It really depends on the Qt configuration. You can statically link only what you need and compress the executable (see [UPX](http://Upx.sourceforge.net)) to get a much smaller output.

As for installation, there is no framework to install. Just bundle the appropriate DLL files if you do not use static linking.

Note that the answer is different on non Windows platforms. You did not specify, but I assumed Windows because of the .NET (and not Mono) reference.

Comment: To clarify: for .NET, you need to have the .NET runtime installed on your computer, which interprets the bytecode you've built - think of it like Java, where the JRE runs your compiled Java code. This is not like Qt: you need to include the DLLs or statically link for your program to run, like any other library, but the end user does not need a separate interpreter to run Qt code.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not have any relation to .NET.

As for the other part of the question, I admit I find it a bit strange. Why include all those libraries if you're only writing hello world? Keep in mind, even when you write hello world in typical C++ you include iostream which is a library, but that has barely any overhead. On my computer it compiles to about 6kb.

Comment: I think he's asking for what size overhead to expect when using Qt for a complex project, which can be measured as about the size of a very trivial one - hello world. Also, your compiled binary size seems far too small to me to be using Qt: are you linking dynamically and/or forgetting to include the size of Qt itself?

Comment: I was referring to the hello world using C++ with only iostream. I find it strange though to care about the overhead much, because in a complex project these things are recognized as necessary to the application and obviously there will be some overhead. Qt is designed to work on embedded systems as well as desktop ones though, so the overhead should be very minimal.

Comment: I said hello world as it is about the most basic program. I know that if I include the libraries, the difference will be the code I use for networking, GUI, and DB.

Comment: Upvoting your comment, @LainIwakura, since you are exactly right: the size is the size, and any user of Qt will be hard-pressed to find a leaner framework of comparable capability when you start factoring in all the complexities that it manages for you.